# How to make a quiz on SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, survey

I'm looking to make a quiz via SharePoint that can tell us which answers each student on right/wrong. So far, all I'm able to get is more of a survey or things we would have to correct manually (which would take us ages).

We're unfortunately unable to use codes or anything like that, so I'm not even sure this is entirely possible, but I thought I'd ask!

Also, I'm working with SP 2013 (and am a bit newer to SP!). Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is the quiz a kind of test?  If so, do you wish to prevent students seeing each others answers?  If yes, this can be managed from List Settings.  As the other respondents have suggested, you could use either a Survey or a Standard List, the latter could be configured to use Choice fields as much as possible - standard answers are easier for analysis>you can export data to Excel for easy analysis if you wish.  Otherwise Sharepoint can also be configured to perform some kinds of analysis too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check OOTB survey list in SharePoint. I think without customization it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Survey list type to create a quiz. You can ask questions, provide different answer types, have conditional questions, etc. You can configure it to allow users to only view their own responses (so no one cheats). From there, your 'grading' would have to be done manually, there isn't anything that would say they answered wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a list with questions and correct answers.
- Create another list where the students submit the answers.
- Create a designer workflow, which compares each answer with the correctanswers list and increment the score accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers @ the following link
https://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-manage-training-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Apart from link of solution..it is good practice to add some explanation about answer from the link...

Answer (score 0):

Surveys may not be the best way to capture answer to questions and then find out the correct answer because you are unable to create calculated columns to validate this on the fly. I would recommend using a Custom List to do this. (assuming many of your questions could be multiple choice)

1. Create custom list with Choice Columns
2. Create Calculated Columns to validate the "Correct" answer for each question.
3. You can set up a [Me] filtered default view so users can see their own items or use Item level Permissions in the advanced settings of the list so contribute users can only create / view their own items. (Designers or Full control users would be able to view all)
4. Other views could be for the admins to review the answers or to export them to excel etc.

Here is the formula I used to choose each answer to the questions in my example below.

```
#Answer 1 - Calculated Column Displaying text
=IF([Question 1]="2. Answer B","Correct","Incorrect")
#Answer 2 - Calculated Column Displaying text
=IF([Question 2]="3. Answer Three","Correct","Incorrect")
```

[image]

If you do use a Survey List you can do all sorts of cool things but you will be grading them manually.